# OpenCVSharp and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build a project using opencvsharp v2.4 64x in Visual Studio 2012. The project is built using .net 4.5 and x64 target. I've installed VS08+VS10 sp1 prerequisites. i've included all the opencv dlls (version 2.4.0 64x) in my project to copy to executable directory including TBB.dll (and checked that they actually end up in the correct folder).

However, on running the software i get the error: An exception has occurrred because of P/Invoke. Please check the following ... System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core204' ... etc

any ideas why this is happening? maybe VS2012 is not supported to build opencvsharp 2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like i still missed out a few native dll's which code204 was dependent on.
here is the complete list that is required. It now works in visual studio 2012 with 64-bit and .net 4.5 - however a few examples wont run (delaunay) using 4.5 but only in 3.5. no idea why...

```
OpenCvSharpExtern.dll
OpenCvSharpExternGpu.dll
opencv_calib3d240.dll
opencv_calib3d240d.dll
opencv_contrib240.dll
opencv_contrib240d.dll
opencv_core240.dll
opencv_core240d.dll
opencv_features2d240.dll
opencv_features2d240d.dll
opencv_ffmpeg240.dll
opencv_ffmpeg240_64.dll
opencv_flann240.dll
opencv_flann240d.dll
opencv_gpu240.dll
opencv_gpu240d.dll
opencv_highgui240.dll
opencv_highgui240d.dll
opencv_imgproc240.dll
opencv_imgproc240d.dll
opencv_legacy240.dll
opencv_legacy240d.dll
opencv_ml240.dll
opencv_ml240d.dll
opencv_nonfree240.dll
opencv_nonfree240d.dll
opencv_objdetect240.dll
opencv_objdetect240d.dll
opencv_photo240.dll
opencv_photo240d.dll
opencv_stitching240.dll
opencv_stitching240d.dll
opencv_ts240.dll
opencv_ts240d.dll
opencv_video240.dll
opencv_video240d.dll
opencv_videostab240.dll
opencv_videostab240d.dll
QtCore4.dll
QtGui4.dll
tbb.dll
tbbmalloc.dll
tbbmalloc_debug.dll
tbbmalloc_proxy.dll
tbbmalloc_proxy_debug.dll
tbb_debug.dll
tbb_preview.dll
tbb_preview_debug.dll
```